# Cypress. Get a list of opened tabs

Tags: cypress

Is it possible to make a list of opened tabs?
The case is:

1. I click on a button
2. It generates the link and opens it in a new tab
3. I have to navigate to this page and do some verifications

In case that Cypress does not support multi-tabs. It would be good to have a list of the opened tabs. So I can navigate to them.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs.html#Multiple-tabs), Cypress'll never have multi-tabs support. What you could do, however, for your test case is:

- Check the links open in new tabs like so: `cy.get('a[href="/index"]').should('have.attr', 'target', '_blank')`.
- Visit the `href` like so: `cy.visit('/index.html')`.
- Assert the visited page's content.

If you need inspiration, you could use [this recipe](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/testing-dom__tab-handling-links) for handling tabs & links.

Comment: It is a good solution when I can take the URL from an element.

But in my case, the new URL is generated and is opened in a new tab when I click on a button. That is why I am looking for a solution to have a list of all opened tabs